# Converting CFG to a regular expression

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

I have a context free grammar defined by the following rules.

```
S ->  X .
S ->  Y .
X ->  0 X .
X ->  0 A .
Y ->  Y 1 .
Y ->  A 1 .
A -> e (epsilon)
A -> 0 A 1 .
```

I know that this creates the following strings (and many more)

```
1
0
1 1
0 0
1 1 1
0 1 1
0 0 1
0 0 0
1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1
0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0
```

I think I can define this as

```
(0^n)(1^m) or (0^m)(1^n) where m<n
```

but how can I define this formally as a regular expression?

Comment: You can't. Regular expressions do not always correspond to context-free languages.  This problem is an example (assuming you've derived the language correctly). Said another way, the set of regular languages is a *proper* subset of the set of CFLs.

Comment: Is this because we have two exponents where m has a relation to n?

Comment: It has to do with the exponents, @maracuja, but not so much with the fact that there are two of them. Rather, regular expressions/automata/grammars have only finite memory. This means that they can count up to a fixed number, no more. If you need to compare arbitrarily large m and n this cannot be done by regular means.

Comment: Thank you both this makes sense. However, I still have one problem. when you have a regular expressionssuch as 0*1, is this not a similar situation where we have an arbitrarily large 0?